# Move RAID 1 Array to new system

Tags: server, partitioning, raid, mdadm

I am rebuilding my Ubuntu home server, but I want to preserve my two disks currently in Linux software RAID 1.

My current config is:

One 240GB HDD configured as OS Disk (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)
Two 3TB WD Reds configured as Linux RAID 1 - contains home files, pictures, videos, backups, etc

For a number of reasons, I need to re-build the system on a new OS Disk with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, which will be a 240GB SSD.  With the new system, is there a way to mount the two RAID drives without (a) losing data and (b) needing to rebuild the RAID array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [David Foerster's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/529845/527764), I moved forward.  I was able to successfully migrate the RAID volume.  One detail that complicated the move was that I had the RAID array as part of the LVM Group.  So once I had the new system re-built, the RAID array was recognized, but I was unable to mount any of the LVMs.

I ended up having to use vgexport/vgimport to export and import the volume group.  It is a good thing I was installing to a new OS Disk, meaning I still had my old OS disk, which allowed me to revert back and properly export LVMs.  The procedure I followed is [here on tldp.org](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recipemovevgtonewsys.html)(except this is missing the deactivation and reactivation of logical volumes).

My original configuration was:

1. 2x3TB Disks in Linux RAID1 with a single Ext4 partition for file storage data (no OS).
2. 3TB RAID array added as the sole device within volume:  `/dev/NASRaid1/NAS_LVM`
3. `/dev/NASRaid1/NAS_LVM` mounted to filesystem as `/nfs`

Steps taken to export and import the volume were:

1. Unmount filesystem(s):  unmount `/nfs`
   (I also had an export mirror for a Samba share that I had to un-mount as well)
2. Deactivate logical volume(s):  `lvchange -an /dev/NASRaid1/NAS_LVM`
3. Deactivate volume group:  `vgchange -an NASRaid1`
4. Export the volume group:  `vgexport NASRaid1`
5. Add RAID Array to new system and boot up.  Running `pvscan` lists the exported volume group(s).
6. Import the volume group:  `vgimport NASRaid1`
7. Activate the volume group:  `vgchange -ay NASRaid1`
8. Activate the volume(s):  `lvchange -ay /dev/NASRaid1/NAS_LVM`
9. Mount the filesystem(s):  `mkdir -p /nfs; mount /dev/NASRaid1/NAS_LVM /nfs`

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

mdadm stores all the necessary info to reassemble a RAID in the volume header. As soon as you configure it correctly in your new system it should pick up the existing volumes.